# Commutator subgroup of a group of order $8q$, where $q$ is odd prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

> Let $G=\langle a,b :a^8=b^q=1,a^{-1}b a=b^{-1}\rangle$ be a group of order $8q$, ($q$ is odd prime). Then what will be the commutator subgroup of this group $G$.

What have I done: If $x$ and $y$ be any two elements of $G$, such that $x,y \in \langle a\rangle$ or $x,y \in \langle b\rangle$ then $[x,y]=1$, and if $x \in \langle a\rangle ,~ y \in \langle b\rangle$ then $x=a^{i},~ y=b^j,~\text{for some $i~\text{and}~ j$}$, then the commutator $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=a^ib^ja^{-i}b^{-j} \in \langle b^2\rangle$. This is similar like commutator operation in Dihedral groups $D_n$ of order $2n$. But if $x=a^ib^j$ and $y=a^lb^m$, for integers $i,j,l ~\text{and}~m$ then what we can do for $[x,y]$. I am stuck here,  please help me.

Comment: Please use langle and rangle instead of plain < and >

Comment: @ajotatxe, ok sir

Comment: @Bernard please take a look on the question.

Comment: Since $q$ is odd,  $\langle b^2 \rangle = \langle b \rangle$ and $G/\langle b\rangle$ is abelian so $[G,G]= \langle b\rangle$

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for giving this hint, but how can we say that $\langle b \rangle $ is the smallest normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $G/H$ is abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt and How can we say that $G/<b>$ is abelian?

Comment: Try and solve it yourself now.

Comment: @DerekHolt It's ok sir I got that why $G/<b>$ is abelian, but still I don't know that why $<b>$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/<b>$ is abelian.

Comment: I have explained that already why $b \in [G,G]$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok sir, thanks for your kind hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing here to make this thread answered.  First, let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $b$.  Then, as seen, $H$ is normal and isomorphic to $C_q$, where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$.  We have the splitting exact sequence of groups
$$1\to H \to G \to C_8\to 1\,.$$
Thus, $G/H\cong C_8$ is abelian, so the commutator subgroup $K$ of $G$ is contained in $H$.  It is easy to see that $K=H$.

Now, from the above paragraph, we see that $G$ is the internal semidirect product $\langle b\rangle\rtimes \langle a\rangle$, with $\langle b\rangle\cong C_q$ and $\langle a\rangle\cong C_8$. 
 Writing each element of $G$ as $b^ua^v$ with $v\in\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ and $u\in\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, the multiplication rule of $G=\langle b\rangle\rtimes \langle a\rangle$ is given by
$$\left(b^na^m\right)\cdot \left(b^la^k\right)=b^{n+(-1)^mk}a^{m+l}$$
for all $n,k\in\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ and $m,l\in\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: thank you sir, can you tell me that what mapping are you using from $G$ to $C_8$?

Comment: From the presentation of $G$, you can write any element of $G$ as $b^ua^v$.  Then, show that the map $G\to \langle a\rangle$ sending $b^ua^v\mapsto a^v$ is a surjective group homomorphism (with kernel being precisely $\langle b\rangle=H$).

Comment: sorry for silly question but this is my last doubt, $b^ua^v$ and $a^vb^u$ are different elements here, how can we say that the map $f$ is well defined and is an homomorphism?

Comment: They are different, but you can show that $b^ua^v=a^vb^{\text{something}}$.

Comment: Thanks, now I got the key