# Commutator subgroup of $G=\langle a,b,c,d:a^4=b^2=c^2=d^q=1,ab=ba,ac=ca,bc=cb,d^{-1}ad=b,d^{-1}bd=c,d^{-1}cd=ab \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

Let $$G=\langle a,b,c,d:a^4=b^2=c^2=d^q=1,ab=ba,ac=ca,bc=cb,d^{-1}ad=b,d^{-1}bd=c,d^{-1}cd=ab \rangle$$ be a group of order $8q$, where $q$ is an odd prime. I need to compute its commutator for some research. But I do not that how to proceed.Please help me to short out this problem.

Comment: Do the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3392039/commutator-subgroup-of-a-group-of-order-8q-where-q-is-odd-prime) help here, too?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes sir, they are helpming me a lot.

Comment: The question has been correctly answered by Batominovski, but there are a couple of strange features. Firstly, you have a relation $a^4=1$, but the other relations clearly imply that $a^2=1$, which is OK, but putting $a^4=1$ is redundant and confusing. Secondly, the  action of $d$ on $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ by conjugation defines an automorphism of order $7$, so if the order of the group is $8q$, then we must have $q=7$.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks for this, but sir still I can't understand why $q=7$.

Comment: @MANI If your group has order $8q$ then it is the semidirect product $C_2^3\rtimes C_q$, so $C_q$ is acting as an automorphism on $C_2^3$. This automorphism is given by your presentation, and a quick calculation will show you that it has order $7$. This means that $7$ divides $q$, then as $q$ is an odd prime we have $q=7$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$, $b$, and $c$.  Observe that $H$ is isomorphic to $C_2^3$, where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$.  Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.  Now, $G/H$ is a group of order $q$, which must then be isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_q$ (i.e., $G/H$ is abelian).

If $K$ denotes the commutator subgroup of $G$, then we must have $K\leq H$ since $G/H$ is abelian.  You now have to show that $K=H$.

We can determine $G$ precisely from the given information.  Identify $H\cong C_2^3$ with the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^3$, and identify $a$, $b$, and $c$ with the vectors $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ respectively.  Then, the conjugation by $d^{-1}$ (i.e., the map $x\mapsto d^{-1}xd$ for $x\in H$) is given by the matrix
$$\mathbf{D}:=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\,.$$  Thus, $\mathbf{D}^7$ is the identity matrix (over $\mathbb{F}_2$).  However, $\mathbf{D}^q$ is also the identity matrix (as $d^q=1$).  This shows that $q=7$.  Consequently, $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2^3\rtimes \langle \mathbf{D}\rangle\cong C_2^3\rtimes C_7$ with the group multiplication $$(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{D}^k)\cdot (\mathbf{y},\mathbf{D}^l):=(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{D}^k\mathbf{y},\mathbf{D}^{k+l})$$
for all $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{F}_2^3$ and $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$.  (The element $d$ of $G$ is identified with $(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{D}^{-1})$, for example.)

In general, if a nonabelian group $G$ of order $8q$, where $q$ is an odd prime natural number, has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $C_2^3$, then $q\in\{3,7\}$.  This is because $G$ is a semidirect product of $C_2^3$ with $C_q$.  We must then have a nontrivial group homomorphism $\tau:C_q\to \text{Aut}(C_2^3)$ (since $G$ is nonabelian).  However, $\big|\text{Aut}(C_2^3)\big|=7\cdot 6\cdot 4$ and $\tau$ is injective.  Therefore, $q\in\{3,7\}$.  (For the OP's problem, the relations amongst the generators $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ eliminate the possibility that $q=3$.)

As a final note, if $q$ is an odd prime natural number not equal to $7$ and $G$ is the group with the given presentation, then from our earlier work, we can deduce that $d=1$.  Thus, $d^{-1}ad=b$ implies $a=b$.  Similarly, $b=c$ and $c=ab$.  This shows that $a=b=c=1$.  Therefore, $G$ is the trivial group.

Comment: @Batominovski   Thanks for your helpful answer I have a doubt, order of $a$ is 4, so how can you say that $H$ is isomorphic $C_2^3$

Comment: Think carefully and you will find out that $a$ actually has order $2$.

Comment: @Batominovski Sir please take a look, since $d^{-1}cd=ab \Rightarrow (d^{-1}cd)^2=1=(ab)^2=a^2.$ This is the reason I think, $a$ is of order $2$.

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks sir, I have done the job. cay you explain that why $q=7$ quoted by #DerekHolt

Comment: I was writing that.  See the edit just now.  And yes, your reason that $a$ has order $2$ is correct.

Comment: @Batominovski Thank you sir. This place is awesome for newcomers like me in research.